# \.{I} in springer gets mangled in when bbl is produced

Tags: bibtex

I have cited authors whose first or last names start with the capital i in Turkish `\.{I}`in the BibTeX file. I am using `spbasic.bst` and `natbib`

BibTeX produced `.bbl` file with `\{I}` instead of `\.{I}`. With other style files I have used I never had this problem. This does *not* occur with say `\c{S}` in the author names.

Here is a bibtex entry

```
@inproceedings{aycse2011,
  title={Extraction of semantic word relations in {Turkish} from dictionary definitions},
  author={Ay{\c{s}}e {\c{S}}erbet{\c{c}}i and Zeynep Orhan and  {\.{I}}lknur Pehlivan},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the ACL 2011 Workshop on Relational Models of Semantics},
  pages={11--18},
  year={2011},
  organization={Association for Computational Linguistics}
}
```

If I use `{\.I}` it produces  "i", If I use `{\.{I}}` as above, it  does not even go through pdflatex (the . is eaten by bibtex somewhere along the way)

as in

```
\bibitem[{{\c{S}}erbet{\c{c}}i et~al(2011){\c{S}}erbet{\c{c}}i, Orhan, and
  Pehlivan}]{aycse2011}
{\c{S}}erbet{\c{c}}i A, Orhan Z, Pehlivan {\I} (2011) Extraction of semantic
  word relations in {Turkish} from dictionary definitions. In: Proceedings of
  the ACL 2011 Workshop on Relational Models of Semantics, Association for
  Computational Linguistics, pp 11--18
```

and I get

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
l.32 ...}erbet{\c{c}}i A, Orhan Z, Pehlivan {\{I}}
                                                   (2011) Extraction of
```

I believe is specific to spbasic as I did not have a  problem with other bib styles I use frequently (e.g. acl.bst)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried `{\.{I}}`? Otherwise please put a full example of such a bibtex entry

Comment: `spbasic.bst` has an aggresive remove dots macro.  A work around is to put `\newcommand{\dotI}{\.I}` in your preamble and use `{\dotI}` in your bibliography file.